# How to recreate a cell when using UIStoryboard to register cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Now, I think register cell by UIStoryboard is not a good practice. Registering cells by code or xib can use a static varier to prevent other people to change the reuse identifier string. Because you use the variable is not changed.

UITableView register cell by the way below:(I copy from another question)

> Use **“prototype” cells** in the storyboard
> (Create cell UI in the storyboard/nib inside `UITableView`)
> You **should not use either** `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` methods. `UIStoryboard` handles it on its own, since you specified the `reuseIdentifier` in the storyboard, the `tableView` knows which cell is associated with which `reuseIdentifier`.

If I do this with way, the cell is shown normally.

I commit code by Git.

**My question is**

If someone pulls the code and changes the reuse identifier in the Storyboard only.(accidental event)

TableView will not dequeueReusableCell with the old reuse identifier. Then a bug is created.

Then the cell will be nil.
How to recreate a cell with the old reuse identifier and return to the UITableView delegate?

Comment: "changes the reuse identifier in the Storyboard only." Well _don't do that_ and this will not be a problem. It's silly to just change the reuse identifier of a cell, without changing the `dequeueReusuableCell` call, the same way that it is silly to change a class's name only in the declaration, without also changing that class's name wherever you have used it.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, It is a accidental event.

Comment: If it is an accidental event, then just change the identifier back to the old one in the storyboard! Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Sweeper A newbie may forget to change the identifier string in the code.